# kafka.common.OffsetOutOfRangeException

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

Am getting the below error in spark streaming. This works fine for few days but getting the below error after 4-5 days. Can anyone please help me on this.

```
kafka.common.OffsetOutOfRangeException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    at kafka.common.ErrorMapping$.exceptionFor(ErrorMapping.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.handleFetchErr(KafkaRDD.scala:184)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.fetchBatch(KafkaRDD.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.getNext(KafkaRDD.scala:208)
    at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$14.hasNext(Iterator.scala:388)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:126)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:229)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have checked the kafka properties and the default value for log.retention.hours is 7 days. Also executed the below command.

```
kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --describe --topics-with-overrides
```

Got the below output for the topic that is reading from.

```
Topic:consumer_events        PartitionCount:25       ReplicationFactor:3     Configs:retention.ms=43200000,min.insync.replicas=2,cleanup.policy=delete,compression.type=snappy,retention.bytes=644245094400
```

Can anyone please help me on this.

Thanks

Comment: `retention.ms` is set to half day for your topic. Could you set a larger value and retry?

Comment: Hi @amethystic, we have the same retention for other streaming processes and they work fine. We only have issue with this process. Could you please let me know how to increase the retention.ms for the topic. Thanks

Comment: To change `retention.ms`, you could issue command below:
`bin/kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper zk:port --entity-type topics --entity-name consumer_events --alter --add-config retention.ms=<value>`

Comment: Thanks @amethystic. I will give a try and let you know. Thanks.